# fadeOut time for a div

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I use fadeOut for a div in my site.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#messages").fadeOut(5000);
});
```

I want this div show 5 second show, after fadeOut effect.

How can i do?

Comment: You showed absolutely correct code. What browser it didn't work? Check demo please http://jsfiddle.net/LWb2y/

Comment: Oh, you should increase fadeOut timeout for a few sec(for example 7000). And you will resolve this issue without any general timeout. http://jsfiddle.net/LWb2y/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) to delay code execution.

```
setTimeout(function() { $("#messages").fadeOut() }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use settimeout function. See the following link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout